# Suppress "Serializing big strings impacts deserialization performance" log messages

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

Per the title, wondering if it is possible to suppress the "Serializing big strings impacts deserialization performance" warning messages generated by Webpack caching?

If not possible to directly suppress them, is it possible to intercept the Webpack logger to suppress them that way?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the webpack config option [ignoreWarnings](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#ignorewarnings). For example: `someWebpackConfig = { ignoreWarnings: [/Serializing big strings/] }`